# How can you reduce the indices of elements in a string array after deleting an element from it?

Tags: java, arrays

I've got a task, to create a method that takes the elements of a string array, checks if there's a duplicate, then deletes it ( what I tried with "null") and then moves all the other elements towards index value [0] to close the gap(s).

Right now it looks like this:

```
public static boolean deleteTask() {
    boolean removed = false;
    for (int pos = 0; pos < todos.length; pos++) {
        if (todos[pos].equals(titel)) {
            todos[pos] = null;
            removed = true;
   
            if (removed){
                //set pos+1 = pos to reduce each value -1. 
                //repeat process for each index [10]
                }
            }
        }
        return removed;
    }
}
```

In the picture I've shown what I see the result like.
E.g. pos.4 was a duplicate - it was then set to null. Now all the following indexes have to be changed to -1 to fill the gap.
Obviously the index is then set back to 456 instead of 567 this is just to illustrate the movement of the string.

Can you help me move the indexes in -1 direction after [pos] null ?

If you could help with doing the same for 2+ duplicates, that would be even greater.

[image: changingElementsIndexesInArrayJava]

Comment: You know the position of the deleted element and you know what a basic `for` loop is. You also know how the algorithm is, you just drew it. So what exactly is unclear here?

Comment: `[pos +1] = [pos]` ... why +1?

Comment: being on [pos] 4/null, I want to take the string from the right/ next index (or  current position +1   [pos+1] ), which is the 5 in the picture and pull it back to the left current index position [pos]/4 .

Then do the same for 5.6.7 etc until todos.length-1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of

```java
todos[pos + 1] = todos[pos];
```

you should use

```java
todos[pos] = todos[pos + 1];
```

Here is the working code:

```java
public static boolean deleteTask() {
    boolean removed = false;
    for (int pos = 0; pos < todos.length; pos++) {
        if (todos[pos].equals(titel)) {
            todos[pos] = null;
            removed = true;
        }
        if (removed && pos < todos.length - 1) {
            // swap the string with the next one
            // you can't do this with the last
            // element because [pos + 1] will
            // throw an indexoutofbounds exception
            todos[pos] = todos[pos + 1];
        } else if (removed && pos == todos.length - 1) {
            // here you can swap the last one with null
            todos[pos] = null;
        }
    }
    return removed;
}
```

Comment: thank you this one worked, although the logic here is kind of twisted imho.

from my understanding this one is fixating the duplicate and moving it to the back with each iteration after it is taken by the else if to change it to null.  there sure must be a more elegant way in general, but this one is great for now :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`Arrays.stream`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Arrays.html#stream(T%5B%5D)) method to iterate over the elements of this array, [`filter`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Stream.html#filter(java.util.function.Predicate)) out unnecessary elements, or keep only [`distinct`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Stream.html#distinct()) elements, and reassemble the array of the same length as follows:

```java
String[] arr = {"aaaa", "cccc", "aaaa", "bbbb", "aaaa"};

System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arr)); // [aaaa, cccc, aaaa, bbbb, aaaa]
```

```java
String[] arr1 = Arrays.stream(arr)
        .filter(s -> !s.equals("aaaa"))
        .toArray(q -> new String[arr.length]);

System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arr1)); // [cccc, bbbb, null, null, null]
```

```java
String[] arr2 = Arrays.stream(arr)
        .distinct()
        .toArray(q -> new String[arr.length]);

System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arr2)); // [aaaa, cccc, bbbb, null, null]
```

---

<sup>See also:

• [How to find duplicate elements in array in effective way?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65344781/14838237)

• [How to get elements of an array that is not null?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65330013/14838237)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

When using an array, you are going to either shift the values down to close the gap, or just copy the elements into a new smaller array.

Comment: Yes, basically that's what I want to do with this one if that's what you mean by "shifting down".
I need to keep the array size the same for follow up strings.